# Sqlite OperationalError with query returning value

Tags: python, sqlite

Is it possible to execute a commit on a db right after a query returning a value (if this value is not fetched)?
Does a *returning* statement in the query lock the cursor and prevent commits if not fetched?

###### Example/How to reproduce

Given the following table `products`, built as follows:

```
create table products (id INTEGER, name TEXT, price INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

The following query to insert an element can be executed without any error:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query1 = 'insert into products (id, name, price) values (?,?,?)'
cursor.execute(query1, (1, 'apple', 100))
conn.commit()
```

Nevertheless, when using a query returning the id of the element such as

```
query2 = 'insert into products (id, name, price) values (?,?,?) returning id'
cursor.execute(query2, (2, 'cherry', 250))
conn.commit()
```

the following error is raised

```
OperationalError: cannot commit transaction - SQL statements in progress
```

Comment: Why do you need `returning id` if it's not `AUTOINCREMENT`?

Comment: That's just an example. What I would like to understand is the rationale behind this error. Is it due to the cursor locking the db? 
Postgres is working fine with the same code, so is it due to internals of sqlite?

Comment: I've been googling the error message, and it seems to be related to the way Python implicitly commits transactions. I guess this doesn't interact properly with `returning id` doing both an update and also returning a query set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it has been a while on this, but just in case it can help someone else.

In order for your code to work with the *returning* clause, you need to fetch the result first before doing the commit :

```
query2 = 'insert into products (id, name, price) values (?,?,?) returning id'
id = cursor.execute(query2, (2, 'cherry', 250)).fetchone()  # <--- here

print(id)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [lastrowid](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#lastrowid):

```py
query2 = 'insert into products (id, name, price) values (?,?,?)'
cursor.execute(query2, (2, 'cherry', 250))

print(cursor.lastrowid)
```

---